# Force text to wrap inside div with no width

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Is it possible to have text wrap inside an inline-block div which only has a minimum width? (not width, nor max-width)

Here's what I mean:

```
<style type="text/css">

  .container {
    width:100%;
  }

  .field {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width:25%;
  }

  label, input {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .alert {
    display:block;
  }

</style>


<div class="container">

    <div class="field">
      <label style="width:100px;">My Label</label>
      <input style="width:200px;" type="text" />
      <div class="alert">
        This text should wrap at whatever width div.field actually is, and never push div.field out to the width of this text!
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">...another field...</div>
  <div class="field">...another field...</div>
  <div class="field">...another field...</div>
  etc...

</div>
```

Notes:

1. The `label` & `input` are `inline-block` so they stay on the same line, but `div.alert` is `block` so that it appears on a new line underneath the other contents of the field.
2. `div.field` has only MIN-WIDTH (not width, or max-width) because when the user resizes the window (and the width of `div.container`) the following should happen:

   a. If the field's fixed-width inline contents (in this case, LABEL+INPUT=300px) are LESS than 25% of the width of `div.container`, then `div.field` should be exactly 25% of the container width.

   b. If the field's fixed-width inline contents are MORE than 25% of the container, then they should push the field out to their combined width.

So, is there a way to get `div.alert` to wrap based on the width of the field according to the rules above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for an answer for this question and found that the div around the text needs to have:

`max-width: fit-content`

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .field {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  label,
  input {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .alert {
    display: block;
    max-width: fit-content;
  }
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <div>With:</div>
    <label style="width:100px;">My Label</label>
    <input style="width:200px;" type="text" />
    <div class="alert">
      This text should wrap at whatever width div.field actually is, and never push div.field out to the width of this text!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div>Without:</div>
    <label style="width:100px;">My Label</label>
    <input style="width:200px;" type="text" />
    <div>
      This text should wrap at whatever width div.field actually is, and never push div.field out to the width of this text!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I know I's a very old thread, but it might help anyone else.
There's

```
.field {
    width: min-content;
}
```

Which says, that your container shrinks to the least possible. For using it, you must be sure, that the label and the input will be big enough at their minimum width. But with their fixed size it's done. But in this case with the multiple fields, they would be wrapped next to each other, so I suggest

```
.container {
    width: min-content;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxuqhurq/).

It's not totally cross-browser, but [almost](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width).

I found it [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/).

Comment: Think I should accept this answer because it's CSS as requested, and I leveled-up my secret CSS abilities with "min-content" & "max-content" etc. Thanks!   (Psst! Your 'almost' and 'here' links are amusingly reversed.)

Answer (score 2):

Not without jQuery, something like:

```
$('.alert').width($('.alert').parents('.field').width());
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I should have been more specific in that I was looking for a CSS-only solution, but you've answered that anyway. :-)